# index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am calculating simple and Wilder Smoothing but getting this error:
Function:

```
 def Wilder(data, periods):
        start = np.where(~np.isnan(data))[0][0] #Check if nans present in beginning
        Wilder = np.array([np.nan]*len(data))
        Wilder[start+periods-1] = data[start:(start+periods)].mean() #Simple Moving Average
        for i in range(start+periods,len(data)):
            Wilder[i] = (Wilder[i-1]*(periods-1) + data[i])/periods #Wilder Smoothing
        return(Wilder)
```

My dataframe contains columns given below:

```
all_data['prev_close'] = all_data.groupby('symbol')['close'].shift(1)
all_data['TR'] = np.maximum((all_data['high'] - all_data['low']), 
                     np.maximum(abs(all_data['high'] - all_data['prev_close']), 
                     abs(all_data['prev_close'] - all_data['low'])))
for i in all_data['symbol'].unique():
    TR_data = all_data[all_data.symbol == i].copy()
    all_data.loc[all_data.symbol==i,'ATR_5'] = Wilder(TR_data['TR'], 5)
    all_data.loc[all_data.symbol==i,'ATR_15'] = Wilder(TR_data['TR'], 15)

all_data['ATR_Ratio'] = all_data['ATR_5'] / all_data['ATR_15']
```

Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6028\3273810922.py in

```
      5 for i in all_data['symbol'].unique():
      6     TR_data = all_data[all_data.symbol == i].copy()
----> 7     all_data.loc[all_data.symbol==i,'ATR_5'] = Wilder(TR_data['TR'], 5)
      8     all_data.loc[all_data.symbol==i,'ATR_15'] = Wilder(TR_data['TR'], 15)
      9 

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6028\258582860.py in Wilder(data, periods)

      2     start = np.where(~np.isnan(data))[0][0] #Check if nans present in beginning
      3     Wilder = np.array([np.nan]*len(data))
----> 4     Wilder[start+periods-1] = data[start:(start+periods)].mean() #Simple Moving Average
      5     for i in range(start+periods,len(data)):
      6         Wilder[i] = (Wilder[i-1]*(periods-1) + data[i])/periods #Wilder Smoothing
```

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

Comment: Python arrays start at the index ```0```.   So I would believe you use ```Wilder(TR_data['TR'], 4)```   that is assuming that is what you want.

Comment: Now getting this error:   IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

Comment: Then my initial assumption was incorrect.  Do you know what is in your data?